# Post-apocalyptic movie with a man and his dog. Spends his time making traps for zombies

Tags: identify-this-movie

I think it was released in about 2011/2012.

- There is a man and a dog in an abandoned city, with skyscrapers and everything. I think he is trying to get to his family or something.
- In the city also are human/zombie like monsters, that go after him and smell his blood. The man kills them by making traps using his own blood to lure them into the traps.
- At one point the dog gets killed and I think the man gets killed at the end of the movie too.

Comment: Technically vampires, not zombies.

Answer (score 17):

Sounds like the plot of [I Am Legend](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0480249/combined) with Will Smith from 2007.

> It is the year 2012. In the ruins of New York city. Robert Neville who is a military scientist who is the lone survivor of a biochemical disease which was supposed to cure cancer 3 years previous. With only blood thirsty zombies as his neighbors and his trusty dog, Samantha, Robert is trying to discover a cure for this disease and to find out any other people who might have also survived.

He makes traps for the zombies, and...

> the dog dies, and so does the hero in the end.

Here's the trailer:

Comment: I know it's cliched, but in this case, the book *really* was better than the movie. The movie killed the whole premise of the book, which I won't give here to avoid spoilers. Read the book

Comment: They really should've stuck with that [alternate ending](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Am_Legend_%28film%29#Alternate_ending)...

Comment: Even the alternate ending doesn't have the shocking *Oh My God* ending the book had. Again, without spoilers, it doesn't explain why the hero calls himself a legend.

Answer (score 7):

The movie is probably *[I Am Legend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Am_Legend_(film))*, starring Will Smith.

[image]

Will Smith is an Army scientist who survives a plague that kills most of the population and turns the rest into monstrous vampires.  His daughter's dog is his only companion, and dies trying to defend him.

> In 2009, a genetically re-engineered measles virus, originally created as a cure for cancer, turns into a lethal strain which kills 90% of those it infects, and mutates the remaining 10% into predatory, nocturnal mutants called "Darkseekers" who are extremely vulnerable to sunlight and other sources of UV. Three years after the outbreak, US Army virologist Lieutenant Colonel Robert Neville (Will Smith) lives an isolated life in the ruins of New York City, which is now deserted, unsure if any other uninfected humans are left in the world.
>   - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Am_Legend_(film))

The (mediocre) movie is very loosely based on the (excellent) [Richard Mattheson book of the same name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Am_Legend_(novel)).

Comment: Jinx :) [At least the pile-up ended at 2!]

Comment: Well, it would have been a lot better if they just went with the original ending. All that setup showing us how smart those darkseekers are, and in the end, it's all flushed down the drain. Are the pre-screening audiences really worth it? I feel they have about 1:1 success rate :D

Answer (score 1):

If you were looking for an older film, there is [Omega Man](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0067525/) starring Charlton Heston  which is also based on the same book, *I am Legend* as the 2012 Wil Smith version.

Comment: Omega Man is much more faithful to the original source in that it doesn't have zombies. Instead it's got vampires/mutants (depending on your interpretation). So that rules out Omega Man

Comment: @slebetman - 1.  No movie adaptation of *I Am Legend* has been faithful.  Matheson himself has said something like  "I don't know why Hollywood is so fond of my story when no one has ever actually used it."  2.  The creatures in the Will Smith version were vampires, albeit a strange variation on the vampire trope.  They weren't called vampires in universe, but neither were they called zombies.

Comment: Or he means the even older italian version from the 60s ^^

Comment: Geoff Murphy directed a NZ version of the same story in the 80's too, *The Quiet Earth* (http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089869/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1). Popular story ...

Comment: I do not recall Omega Man having a dog though...

Comment: @Luciano (and Plasma): Heston indeed does not have any dog. Price has a poodle briefly, but (1) poodle vs German Shepherd? no contest! and (2) it is infected and he stakes it.

Comment: Also, the first sentence in the question rules *The Omega Man* out...